# How highlight the current label compared to the remaining labels Chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, label

When I hover over a point I want to fade out the remaining labels
[Actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsfy8.png)

I tried with interactive mode as index. This is my code

```
function chartChannelGroup(dataset) {
    ...
    // Create chart
    chartChannelGroupTemp = new Chart(
        $('#chartChannelGroup'), {
        type: 'line', // Adjust as needed
        data: data,
        options: {
                interaction: {
                    mode: 'index'
                },
            responsive: true,
            elements: {
                point: {
                    radius: 0,
                    hitRadius: 10,
                    hoverRadius: 3,
                }
            },,
            ...

}
```

I wish there was a similar result
[expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO1kS.png)